# How to bypass/allow camera options in safari mac using selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a WebRTC on safari but unable to bypass camera/microphone on safari.

On firefox and chrome,automated successfully.

Thanks for your help in advance!!

This code didn't work for me.

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).forEach(function(e){e.type=e.type=='password'?'text':e.type;});");
    //js.executeScript("Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).forEach(function(e){e.type=e.type=='password'?'text':e.type;});");
    js.executeScript("confirm = function(message){return true;};");  
    js.executeScript("alert = function(message){return true;};");  
    js.executeScript("prompt = function(message){return true;}");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[2]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: What _unable to bypass camera/microphone on safari_ mean? Please, describe your problem with more details.

Comment: Pop up window gets open in browser and  asks for allow/deny for camera option.I want to bypass these options and wants always allow for camera.

Answer (score -2):

In Safari 11, you can set the browser to automatically allow websites to access the Camera and Microphone.  In Safari->Preferences->Websites, select Camera, and select Allow for "When visiting other websites".  Do the same for Microphone if you want to enable it as well.

Once this is done, you are not prompted to Allow for camera access.